# how is '@' handled in the softlayer Rest calls

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

## I have an '@' in my user id "12345_name@company.com" , this when passed in the Rest Call is causing the error "Softlayer Access Denied"  .

{
 "error": "Access Denied. ",
 "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"

## }

Please suggest ways to get around this. 
Can we use an Alias instead of the  "12345_name@company.com" user if.

Below is the Rest call I am trying to make.

https://12345_name@company.com:@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask=mask[hostname;domain;id;startCpus;maxCpuUnits;powerState;datacenter[name,longName];maxMemory;powerState;createDate;hourlyBillingFlag;averageDailyPublicBandwidthUsage;billingItem[id,item[id,description],category[name,id],children[id,item[id,description],category[id,name]]];networkComponents[status,ipAddressBindings.ipAddress,id,networkId,primaryIpAddress,port,maxSpeed];networkVlans[subnets[networkIdentifier,networkVlan.primaryRouter.hostname,cidr,gateway,id,netmask,addressSpace,networkVlanId,routingTypeName]]]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that depends on the REST client that you are using, using Insonmia REST client or Chrome I did not get any issue.

try encoding the characters @ like this:

As your user id has an special character, the ‘@’ on this case, you need to use the URL encoding as following:

```
                 https://12345_name%40company.com:@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask........
```

Where %40 is the URL encoding of ‘@’.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's necessary to use "**Basic Authentication**" in order to avoid special characters, in that case, you need to encode your username and apiKey, for example:

> - **username:** 123123_ruber@softlayer.com
> - **apiKey:** 375f50232aaba2d002eca7bc5e9dc4f6a042a8a65982254df8

you need to encode:

- **username** space **apiKey**
- **123123_ruber@softlayer.com 375f50232aaba2d002eca7bc5e9dc4f6a042a8a65982254df8**

A tool I can recommend for encoding:
https://www.base64encode.org/

Here the example encoded:

**MTIzMTIzX3J1YmVyQHNvZnRsYXllci5jb20gMzc1ZjUwMjMyYWFiYTJkMDAyZWNhN2JjNWU5ZGM0ZjZhMDQyYThhNjU5ODIyNTRkZjg=**

It's necessary to add **Basic** word before the credentials encoded

> **Basic MTIzMTIzX3J1YmVyQHNvZnRsYXllci5jb20gMzc1ZjUwMjMyYWFiYTJkMDAyZWNhN2JjNWU5ZGM0ZjZhMDQyYThhNjU5ODIyNTRkZjg=**

Then you can add "**authorization**" as a header like the following example (I used Advanced Rest Client for Chrome):

[image]