# Unable to URL encode { } for object filters in softlayer REST URI

Tags: url-encoding, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am calling a Get method through Rest and my URI contains { } for object filters in Softlayer. I have used %7B for { and %7D for }, but I get java.net.URISyntaxException.

The URI also contains @ which I have replaced with %40. This is working. I am using http Client to execute my Rest Call. The URI works fine on Postman, both with and without URL Encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here two way to skip or handle @:

- [how is '@' handled in the softlayer Rest calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620425/how-is-handled-in-the-softlayer-rest-calls)

Another way to skip special characters would be, using "\" at the start from any of these chars, here an example of this:

- [SoftLayer getUsers by userStatusID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167799/softlayer-getusers-by-userstatusid)

Also, it's necessary to skip **{}": (special chars in objectFilters)**, if you are continue hitting with the exception, would be great if you could provide an example or the exactly code that you are trying, for further assistance

---

### How to get Virtual Guests for a specific datacenter

Here a rest request for **dal05** datacenter:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask%5Bid%2Chostname%5D&objectFilter=%7B%22virtualGuests%22%3A%7B%22datacenter%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A%22dal05%22%7D%7D%7D%7D
```

Comment: This is the URL that I am trying to access.
I have skipped " with a \ , but we cannot do the same for { }.

`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,hostname]&objectFilter={“virtualGuests” :{“datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"dal05”}}}}`

Comment: Could you try the request that I posted in my answer please? Let me know if you have success with that

Comment: %7B is for { and %7D is for }, I had thought i could give a \ for ", but it has to be encoded with %22 and : with %3A.

Thank you for the help.