# SoftLayer API for getting all the devices associated with a tag

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I wanted to get all the devices tagged with a given string using a REST API. I have tried   curl -X GET -u "$user_name:$api_key" https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Tag/iisha7/getReferences  but it didn't work. It is giving this error:

{"error":"Internal Error","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

Does this solve my purpose? or should I use another API? If it does, what is the mistake I am doing? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getTags?objectFilter={"tags":{"name":{"operation":"tag2"}}}&objectMask=mask[references]

Note: replace "tag2" with the name of the tag you are lokking for
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks Nelson, it works from Postman. Can you please tell me how to call it from curl? It gives me the following error when I call it from curl.            curl: (3) [globbing] nested braces not supported at pos 8

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923676/unable-to-url-encode-for-object-filters-in-softlayer-rest-uri you need to enconde the filters  in curl Also I saw somebodies who are able to make it work with the curl options -g -v, but that never worked for me.